# User remains online after losing connection to internet on Ejabberd

Tags: c#, xmpp, ejabberd

**Hi Experts,**

**Problem**
I am using Ejabberd ejabberd-19.09.1-windows. The issue i am facing is when i turn off the wifi and check ejabberd users list through administrator dashboard. The user status remain Online.

**Required Guide/Solution**
I want that Ejabberd should mark the user status Offline as soon as the TCP connection is broken with XMPP. This could be either implicitly by closing XMPP connection or explicitly due to network disconnection

**Mechanism that i am using in C#**

```
public static void Main(){

XmppClientConnection xmpp = new XmppClientConnection();
xmpp.ConnectServer = "serveripaddress";
xmpp.Server = "localhost";
xmpp.Port = "5222";
xmpp.Username = "userid";
xmpp.Password = "userpassword";
xmpp.KeepAlive = true;
xmpp.AutoResolveConnectServer = false;
xmpp.AutoRoster = false;
xmpp.UseStartTLS = false;
xmpp.AutoAgents = false;
xmpp.UseSSL = false;
try
{
    xmpp.Open();
    xmpp.OnSaslStart += new agsXMPP.Sasl.SaslEventHandler(OnSaslStart);
    xmpp.OnLogin += new ObjectHandler(Xmpp_OnLogin);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    
}

Thread.Sleep(500);

if (xmpp.XmppConnectionState == XmppConnectionState.SessionStarted || xmpp.XmppConnectionState == XmppConnectionState.Authenticated)
{
    //success
}
else
{
  //failed
}

}

 private void OnSaslStart(object sender, SaslEventArgs args)
 {
     args.Mechanism = agsXMPP.protocol.sasl.Mechanism.GetMechanismName(MechanismType.PLAIN);
     args.Auto = false;
 }

 private void Xmpp_OnLogin(object sender)
{
     var xmpp = (XmppClientConnection)sender; 
     agsXMPP.protocol.client.Presence p = new agsXMPP.protocol.client.Presence(ShowType.chat, "Online");
     p.Type = PresenceType.available;
     xmpp.Send(p);
     xmpp.OnPresence += new agsXMPP.protocol.client.PresenceHandler((s, pres) => xmpp_OnPresence(xmpp, pres, xmpp.Username)); 
}
```

I couldn't identify that, do i need to make changes to XmppClientConnection or on Ejabberd yml(configuration) file.

**What i have attempted in ejabberd.yml**

```
mod_ping:
    send_pings: true
    ping_interval: 120
    ping_ack_timeout: 60
    timeout_action: kill

mod_push_keepalive:
    #resume_timeout: 60
```

But both of above mentioned mods forcefully destroy the connection even if the user is idle and online after specified interval, whereas i need to destroy connection only if user is offline not on idle state

Your help is much appreciated